# javascript too much recursion?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a script that automatically starts uploading after the data has been enter in the database(I need the autoId that the database makes to upload the file).

When I run the javascript the scripts runs the php file but it fails calling the other php to upload the file.

```
too much recursion
setTimeout(testIfToegevoegd(),500);
```

the script that gives the error

```
send("/projects/backend/nieuwDeeltaak.php",'deeltaakNaam='+f.deeltaaknaam.value+'&beschrijving='+
                        f.beschrijving.value+'&startDatum='+f.startDatum.value+'&eindDatum='+f.eindDatum.value
                        +'&deeltaakLeider='+f.leiderID.value+'&projectID='+f.projectID.value,id);

                    function testIfToegevoegd(){

                        if(document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML == "<b>De deeltaak werd toegevoegd</b>"){
                            //stop met testen + upload file 

                            document.getElementById('nieuwDeeltaak').target = 'upload_target';
                            document.forms["nieuwDeeltaak"].submit()
                        }else{
                            setTimeout(testIfToegevoegd(),500);
                        }

                    }

                    testIfToegevoegd();
```

sorry for the dutch names we have to use them it is a school project.

when I click the button that calls all this for a second time (after the error) it works fine.

Comment: Use a callback rather than polling. The asynchronous nature of AJAX (the first "A" stands for "asynchronous") means callbacks are at its heart, supported by the `onreadystatechange` listener for `XMLHttpRequest`. Is `send` defined by a third party library or your own?

Comment: We had to write our own library for the JavaScript. was lot of experimenting and  searching around how to accomplish the heart of AJAX functions thanks for the tip I'll have a look on the callbacks any tips on where to find good info on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
setTimeout(testIfToegevoegd(),500);
```

should be

```
 setTimeout(testIfToegevoegd,500);
```

you have to pass the function itself, not its result